# How to get the url for admin page (including the key) in magento 2x custom module controller

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I need the page url in Magento 2x including key in my custom module controller.
[here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61490/got-confused-with-custom-adminhtml-controller) something similar but this is for magento 1x. i need for magento 2x.

for magento 1x : `Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/framexport/index')` but i need similar for magento 2x.

Answer (score 7):

The right way is, inject the *UrlInterface* in you model block or whatever class constructor

Then call the *getUrl()* function

```
class SomeClass extends \Some\Other\Class
{

    protected $_backendUrl;

    public function __construct(
        ...........
        ...........
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        ...........
    ) {

        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
    }
    public function someFunction()
    {
        $params = array('some'=>'url_parameters');

        $url = $this->_backendUrl->getUrl("the/url/path", $params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get Admin url By calling

```
$this->getUrl('adminhtml/module/action');
```

Please not that "Context" type of object is loaded in the $this object

Answer (score 2):

You can get admin url as follows:

```
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend
        ) {
         $this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
        }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function getAdminUrl()
    {
        echo $this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `adminhtml/module` creates an extra `admin` slug which does not work.
My solution is:

```
// $this->urlBuilder is defined in __constructor() \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder

$query = [
    'method' => 'confirm',
    'id' => $order->getEntityId()
];
$url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('module', $query);
```

It works well for secure URLs (with keys) and non-default `/admin` URLs, such as `/backend`.